# Exception Handling in Laravel 5.8

Tags: json, laravel, exception, response

I have a VehicleController. There, I check the `$request->vehicle` coming from the route. The result is supposed to be car, train or plane. Below is the code.

I have the legitimate vehicle array.

```
protected static $vehicle_arr = array('car', 'train', 'plane');
```

And I check it like so.

```
    private static function _isLegitimateVehicle($vehicle)
    {
        static::$_is_legitimate_vehicle = in_array($vehicle, static::$vehicle_arr);

        if (!static::$_is_legitimate_vehicle) {
            throw new Exception(ModelNotFoundException);
        }
    }
```

There, I throw exception ModelNotFoundException.

In the App\Exception\Handler.php,

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
                return response()->json([
                    'errors' => 'Model Not Found',
                ], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, in postman, it response like below. (this is because of `throw new Exception` in `_isLegitimateVehicle()`.

```
{
     "message": "Use of undefined constant ModelNotFoundException - assumed 'ModelNotFoundException' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)",
     "exception": "ErrorException"
}
```

I want to response json including errors defined in render method.

> can I do that? and is it best practice to handle exception in laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
throw new ModelNotFoundException;
```

Not:

```
throw new Exception(ModelNotFoundException);
```

ModelNotFoundException extends Exception down the line, it is an Exception itself.